# Get maximum value across all columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

how do i get the maximum primary key of all tables in my DB (mysql) ?

I have following query to retrieve `all columns from all tables` that are **primary key** and is **INT** datatype from `my_db` database

```
SELECT 
    table_name, column_name
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    table_schema = 'my_db'
        AND column_key = 'PRI'
        AND data_type LIKE '%int%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME , COLUMN_NAME
```

but now, I'm stucked at getting the maximum values from all these columns across all table. Is there a way to achieve this? My expected output would be single integer number which is the largest across all these columns.

Thank you!

Comment: Probably you can query all three tables using `UNION ALL` and get the `MAX` from there..

Comment: thanks, i have followed your suggestion
``` lang-sql
select id from table_1
union 
select id from table_2
union
select id from table_3
order by id desc limit 1```  
it works fine, however what if the name of those tables & columns (table_N & `id`) is unknown to me and i need to run query to retrieve them (eq. query on the question above) . is there a way to chain them together? 
thanks

Comment: sorry, it's rather hard to format code in comment, here's the sql i run  
`select id from table_1 union select id from table_2 union select id from table_3 order by id desc limit 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the columns have a compatible type (which you are checking for), then you can construct the query using the metadata:

```
select group_concat(replace(replace('select max([column_name]) from [table_name]', '[column_name]', column_name), '[table_name]', table_name)
                    separator '\nunion all\n')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_schema = 'my_db' and
     column_key = 'PRI' and
     data_type LIKE '%int%'
order by TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

I would just copy the query and run it.  But you can automate the process more by assigning the resulting string a variable and using `prepare`/`exec`.

Comment: wow, that's awesome. here's my complete implementation  set @a = ( `<above query>` )  
`prepare stmt from @a;`  `execute stmt;`  `deallocate prepare stmt;`.  please let me know if i miss out anything.  thank you

Comment: @HendryAng . . . That's fine.